# Commutator implies division of phase space in cells of area $h$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator, phase-space

There is a detail from a very well-written answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47458/) that interested me. Unfortunately Springer is charging 41 Euros to access the paper cited by the author.

I wonder if someone could elaborate on an assertion about the commutator ($PX - XP = -i \hbar $):

> "Heisenberg [cite omitted], realizes that this is a splitting up of phase space into cells of dimension $h$ and uses this to deduce an approximate uncertainty principle."

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63318/2451, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/332732/2451 and links therein.