# Hilbert space structure of quantum mechanics in the context of holography

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, holographic-principle

These is a question about the Hilbert space structure of quantum mechanics in the context of holography. See page 175 of Thomas Hartman's [notes](http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2015/gravity-lectures.pdf) on Quantum Gravity and Black Holes.

---

**In quantum mechanics in the context of holography, why is the Hilbert space finite-dimensional only for a *finite* region?**

Comment: Your questions are pretty unclear, you should clarify exactly what you mean.

Comment: *In quantum mechanics, why is the Hilbert space finite-dimensional only for a finite region?* – as a counterexample, consider a 1-dimensional particle in the finite cavity. The Hilbert space is given by a superposition of (an infinite number of) Fourier modes, which is what mathematicians indeed call the Hilbert space.

Comment: @ Solenodon Paradoxus: Do you mean that the Hilbert space of a quantum mechanical system in a finite region not necessarily finite-dimensional?

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean. It is almost always infinite-dimensional.

Comment: But the first line in page 175 of the linked notes say otherwise!

Comment: I took a quick look in the notes, it seems like we are in the context of holographic principle. This is highly non-obvious, quantum gravity-related, etc. You should've emphasized it in the title, the body and the tags of your question.

Comment: In the context of holography, it is *conjectured* that Hilbert spaces of compact regions are finite and that their dimensionality depends exponentially on the *area* of the region's boundary. This is just a conjecture, it needs both a more rigorous context (i.e. AdS/CFT or spin networks in LQG) in which it is strictly realized, and lots of experimental evidence.

Comment: In the context of ordinary quantum mechanics, the rule of thumbs is that quantum theories on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space corresponds to classical theories on a compact _phase space_ (roughly you expect the dimension of the Hilbert space to be $V/\hbar$ where $V$ is the volume of the phase space, this is related to eg [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63318/phase-space-in-quantum-mechanics-and-heisenberg-uncertainty-principle?rq=1)).

Comment: Note that typically phase spaces arise as cotangent bundles on configuration spaces, and are thus non compact, even if the configuration space is. But the 2-sphere can for example be given the structure of a phase space, of which eg the finite-dimensional spin $1/2$ is an admissible quantization, see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/285314/132157).